# Javascript regex replace not working ie

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

I am doing some logic to a string and everything workes fine in Firefox. Found error in IE but confused to fix it.

```
var txt=[], regg=/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,l), g=j=0;
var match = null;
while(match = regg.exec( str )){
    var f = (regg.lastIndex-match.index);
    txt.push([match[0], match.index, regg.lastIndex, f]);
}
```

In the above code if I call `regg.exec( str )` before while then then working in IE. But don't understand why to call.

Also observed that `ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,l)` is not accepting for IE.

Guys, Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,l), g=j=0;....ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,l);   remove g=j=0;

Comment: I need that g=j=0; I am using it later this code

Comment: Is there any errors or it just doesn't do what it should?

Comment: remove 'i' at end regg=/<\/?[^>]+>/g and tyr

Comment: I get 'i' is Not define error in My IE

Comment: @Kamarey: No Error, Just skipping those lines.

Comment: @K6t: in gi 'i' is meant to consider all over the string. anyway tried it, no luck

Comment: please specify version of IE that you're testing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,l)
```

the 'l' char is not a number, but a text character. Replace it with a number you need.

Also to see javascript errors:

In FF install and open [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

In IE go to: Tools-> Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Browsing section, and uncheck the "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)"

Comment: That's actually I can appreciate a nice eye sight. But letter l is giving me a number. I just checked with an alert. :)

Comment: Can you post the whole code including the specific text you are using as input?

Answer (score 0):

dude I thin i got

r u define l;
any thing in ur coding,,
 then leave my anser

```
ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,l)// u entered

ost=str.replace(regg,'').substr(0,1)// my suggestion
```

Comment: l is the string length. I find only issue is if I call regg.exec( str ) before while condition then working fine but confused why to call?. If not I am getting null